# Insert non dupes values in a common table using merge technics in Oracle12

Tags: sql, merge, oracle11g

good day!

I need to optimize my query. It works, but too large, I think.
There is the same logic in my query, I think, it could be shorter.
But I dont know how.

here it is:

```
--TEST
DROP TABLE BL_CL.CLS_TEST;
CREATE TABLE BL_CL.CLS_TEST (
    FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID NUMBER,
    FORM_OF_PAYMENT VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
    SOURCE_SYSTEM VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
    SOURCE_FILE VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
    UDATE_DT DATE
);
COMMIT;
--

MERGE INTO BL_CL.CLS_TEST CE_TEST
USING (SELECT DISTINCT S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT FROM SA_ONLINE_SALES.SA_ONLINE_SALES_SRC S) SA_ST
ON (SA_ST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID = CE_TEST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN         
        INSERT (CE_TEST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, CE_TEST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT, CE_TEST.SOURCE_SYSTEM, CE_TEST.SOURCE_FILE, UDATE_DT)
        VALUES(SA_ST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, SA_ST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT, 'SA_STORES', 'SA_STORES', SYSDATE);

MERGE INTO BL_CL.CLS_TEST CE_TEST
USING (SELECT DISTINCT S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT FROM SA_OFFLINE_SALES.SA_OFFLINE_SALES_SRC S) SA_ST
ON (SA_ST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID = CE_TEST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN         
        INSERT (CE_TEST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, CE_TEST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT, CE_TEST.SOURCE_SYSTEM, CE_TEST.SOURCE_FILE, UDATE_DT)
        VALUES(SA_ST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, SA_ST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT, 'SA_STORES', 'SA_STORES', SYSDATE);
        
SELECT * FROM BL_CL.CLS_TEST order by FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID;
```

So, I need this query to be shorter.

Comment: You *DO NOT* need the `COMMIT;` after the `CREATE TABLE`. DDL statements commit implicitly. You *DO* need a `COMMIT;` after your `MERGE` commands, before the `SELECT`. What do you mean by "shorter"? It looks pretty straight forward as it is...

Comment: No, you should not find diffs) 
First part merges in empty table from one source, second part merges in the same table from another source. If it looks pretty - ok). pmdba, thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 1):

Please try below two variations:

Replacing distinct with row_number() to get the first row for each group.

```
    MERGE INTO BL_CL.CLS_TEST CE_TEST
    USING (select S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT from (SELECT 
S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT, 
    row_number()over(partition by S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT order by S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT)rn  FROM SA_OFFLINE_SALES.SA_OFFLINE_SALES_SRC S)t where rn=1) SA_ST
    ON (SA_ST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID = CE_TEST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN         
            INSERT (CE_TEST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, CE_TEST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT, CE_TEST.SOURCE_SYSTEM, CE_TEST.SOURCE_FILE, UDATE_DT)
            VALUES(SA_ST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, SA_ST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT, 'SA_STORES', 'SA_STORES', SYSDATE);
```

Instead of Merge use Insert since there are not update portion of query:

with SA_ST as
(
SELECT  S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT,row_number()over(partition by S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT order by S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, S.FORM_OF_PAYMENT) rn FROM SA_ONLINE_SALES.SA_ONLINE_SALES_SRC S)
)

```
insert INTO BL_CL.CLS_TEST (CE_TEST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, CE_TEST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT, CE_TEST.SOURCE_SYSTEM, CE_TEST.SOURCE_FILE, UDATE_DT)
select SA_ST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID, SA_ST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT, 'SA_STORES', 'SA_STORES', SYSDATE from SA_ST
where not exists 
(
  select 1 from BL_CL.CLS_TEST  inner join SA_ST  on  (SA_ST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID = CE_TEST.FORM_OF_PAYMENT_ID)
)
```